# MuPDF Android Pdf fit to the screen

Tags: android, mupdf

I succesfully installed MuPDF for one of my Android Apps. But the problems is, while rendering I cannot fit the PDF to the screen. Can anybody please suggest me how to achieve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the measureView method in ReaderView.java to become.

```
private void measureView(View v) {
        // See what size the view wants to be
        v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        // Work out a scale that will fit it to this view
        float scale;
        if (getWidth()>getHeight())
        {
            scale = (float)getWidth()/(float)v.getMeasuredWidth();
            MIN_SCALE = (float)v.getMeasuredWidth()/(float)getWidth();
            MAX_SCALE = MIN_SCALE*5.0f;
        }
        else
            scale = Math.min((float)getWidth()/(float)v.getMeasuredWidth(),
                        (float)getHeight()/(float)v.getMeasuredHeight());

        // Use the fitting values scaled by our current scale factor
        v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY | (int)(v.getMeasuredWidth()*scale*mScale),
                View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY | (int)(v.getMeasuredHeight()*scale*mScale));
    }
```

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that it will not properly render the initial pdf view to the new calculated scale (it's rendered for 1.0f scale). Only after doing some interaction (touching, panning, scaling) it will render properly. Any ways to force the initial rendering to the new scale ?

Comment: This is an old post can't go throw it again.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting errors with regard to the MAX and MIN scale final variables, however I made a slight modification to @hassan83's solution. My solution is tested in MuPDF version 1.9a

```
private void measureView(View v) {
    // See what size the view wants to be
    v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    // Work out a scale that will fit it to this view
    float scale;
    //landscape orientation
    if (getWidth() > getHeight())
    {
        scale = (float)getWidth()/(float)v.getMeasuredWidth() * (1.0f ); //make sure that we fill the page by multiplying with a scale factor of one
    }
    else
        scale = Math.min((float)getWidth()/(float)v.getMeasuredWidth(),
                (float)getHeight()/(float)v.getMeasuredHeight());

    // Use the fitting values scaled by our current scale factor
    v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY | (int)(v.getMeasuredWidth()*scale*mScale),
            View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY | (int)(v.getMeasuredHeight()*scale*mScale));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with this the page is resized boot too larger from the view. here is the "measureview" method in my code:

```
    private void measureView(View v) {
    // See what size the view wants to be
    v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

    if (!mReflow) {
        // Work out a scale that will fit it to this view
        float scale = Math.min((float) getWidth() / (float) v.getMeasuredWidth(),
                (float) getHeight() / (float) v.getMeasuredHeight());
        // Use the fitting values scaled by our current scale factor
        v.measure(MeasureSpec.AT_MOST | (int) (v.getMeasuredWidth() * (scale + 0.8f) * mScale),
                MeasureSpec.AT_MOST | (int) (v.getMeasuredHeight() * (scale+0.8f) * mScale));
    } else {
        v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY | (int) (v.getMeasuredWidth()),
                View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY | (int) (v.getMeasuredHeight()));
    }
}
```

this is what I need, boot the page need to be fetched in exactly in the view, boot with the text readable.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21168243/2982225,
you can re-render the view by adding the following code at the end:

```
requestLayout();
post(this);
```

again.

So the complete code is as follows (attribution for code before last comment: [the accepted answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21168243/2982225) ):

```
private void measureView(View v) {
        // See what size the view wants to be
        v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        // Work out a scale that will fit it to this view
        float scale;
        if (getWidth()>getHeight())
        {
            scale = (float)getWidth()/(float)v.getMeasuredWidth();
            MIN_SCALE = (float)v.getMeasuredWidth()/(float)getWidth();
            MAX_SCALE = MIN_SCALE*5.0f;
        }
        else
            scale = Math.min((float)getWidth()/(float)v.getMeasuredWidth(),
                        (float)getHeight()/(float)v.getMeasuredHeight());

        // Use the fitting values scaled by our current scale factor
        v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY | (int)(v.getMeasuredWidth()*scale*mScale),
                View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY | (int)(v.getMeasuredHeight()*scale*mScale));

        // last comment
        // to force the initial rendering to the new scale

        requestLayout();
        post(this);
    }
```

Hope this helps.