# How I can resize the text of the pages using mupdf in android

Tags: android, mupdf

I port my own app to read pdf files in android using mupdf, all is working fine here, but the text on the pages appear very small, so how I can resize the font or scale the view to be more readable for a myopic User?

Someone can help-me

Comment: I got this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063005/mupdf-android-pdf-fit-to-the-screen/28844533#28844533
but I try to implement it and not solve my problem
someone cam help?
thank's

Comment: You cannot change the font size, as this is fixed in the PDF file. If you changed the size of the font you would have to reflow the text which you can't do with PDF. You can change the resolution at which you render the PDF page which will produce a larger bitmap.

Comment: Hi @KenS!
Thank you for reply!
sorry for my wrong expression, what I need is just increase the size of the image on the page that appears on the screen, so that the User can read normally, because as it is, appears with the very small letters, and I am myopic. But I've tried everything. even managed to increase the view size on the screen but the text is still small, maybe you could tell me how I can do this, i would be very grateful.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not an Android developer. I'll pass it to the correct person, but he's on vacation until the end of the week.

Comment: Nice!
Thank You!
I'll wait!

Comment: @ArmandoMarquesSobrinho did you solved it..?

Comment: Thank you for the responcd @SaravanaKumarChinnaraj !
I stopped this project for now, have another projects published with cling my atenttion.

Answer (score 0):

mupdf has two versions, one is mini and the other is old.

the "old" has reflow function, which can enlarge font by zooming in with two fingers.

but i do not think it is perfect because the text is not justified, so the right margin is huge and ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You just increase the scale level in MUPDF.
private static final float MAX_SCALE = 10.0f;(RenderView.class),
I hope its help you.its working in my app.